# Using third party software with EMR

Tags: emr

Is it possible to use a third party software within an emr cluster, ie to make each node able able to use this software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can use third party software within emr cluster.

In your bootstrap script you can install software in your cluster. You can upload the software in amazon s3 and in bootstrap script , try to download the software and install.

it will be available to each node as in bootstrap all of them install it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand you well, the software installation must be made fully automatable ?

Comment: yes we should automate using script. A simple  shell script will do.